# What can we do get a layout like this using just flex?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, less

I want a layout like this, how can I write the CSS code?

[image]

My HTML (I have moved my CSS in styles in HTML):

```
<div class="container" style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
    <div class="orange" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <div id="chart" />
    </div>
    <div class="yellow" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <LineChart
        width={600}
        height={300}
        data={this.state.data2}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="pv"
          stroke="#8884d8"
          activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
        />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: could you show us your attempts? so we can help you with your css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex comes handy to properly position and size the *sidebar* and *content* elements, as in the example below.

No need for any fixed pixel width nor using flex for *header* and *footer* which are simple block elements.

```css
.header { background: red; }
.sidebar { background: orange; }
.content { background: yellow; }
.footer { background: green; }

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
    flex: 1;
}

.content {
    flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if sidebar & the content are in a container with `display: flex`, you can achieve this with the following styling

```
.sidebar {
  // set width
  width: 200px; // for example
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Although you might consider a fixed sidebar, this is how you achieve the layout on your picture.